# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Vs SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

SQL server 2008 r2 has slow execution of cross joins queries. It is creating too many issues in our system. Can migration on Sql server 2012 solve the cross join issue. Earlier we are using sql 2005 where we have not such issues. but we cant move back now. I don't know this solve my issue or not. And performance wise 2012 is better then 2008 r2 in executing cross join queries?

```
select '37' as orddate,brand from maindb1.dbo.contract_report where jobnumber in (select      distinct [Job Number] from maindb1.dbo.v_alltype_st where [day] like '%2012' and DATEPART(WEEK,CONVERT(datetime,[DAY],103))='37') and brand<>'' and brand<>'N/A'
```

the above run in around 7 minute and the below one in around 32 seconds

```
select brand from maindb1.dbo.contract_report where jobnumber in (select distinct [Job Number] from maindb1.dbo.v_alltype_st where [day] like '%2012' and DATEPART(WEEK,CONVERT(datetime,[DAY],103))='37') and brand<>'' and brand<>'N/A'
```

the only difference is that above one has one extra field.

the one is table and one is view. This is not the only example.

Comment: Install it on a comparable machine and run some tests.

Comment: Agree with Chris's comment, but if you post some details of your query, we may be able to help.

Comment: Maybe you could show a slow query, describe the indexes that support the query, show an actual execution plan, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing performance problems on 2008 R2 that you didn't see on 2005, and this database was upgraded directly or migrated via backup/restore or detach/attach, you should be sure to:

(a) manually [update statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on all relevant tables

(b) ensure you [set compatibility level to 100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

In general, SQL Server 2012 should provide underlying performance enhancements, mainly due to improvements in the optimizer. I don't believe there are any enhancements specific to cross joins, but I'm also not privy to the source code, so it would be tough to know that anyway.

Comment: Then yes, you'll need to - at a minimum - perform comparison tests *after* updating statistics and upgrading the compatibility level.